# Pandas DF NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these lines of code reading and writing an excel:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name, header=[0, 1])
df.to_excel(output_path, index=False)
```

When it tries to write the excel I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and I cannot find a concrete answer online.

Please help.

Comment: [check this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11292#issuecomment-147580689)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply set `index=True` instead of False

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are having multi index in your dataframe.
You can either reset_index() or drop your level=1 index.

If you don't want index then you can insert a column as index
df.insert(0,df.index,inplace=False) #something like this

Answer (score 0):

Multi-index columns can actually be exported to Excel. You just have to set index=True.

So for the example the solution becomes...

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name, header=[0, 1])
df.to_excel(output_path, index=True)
```

NB. This is true as of Pandas version 1.2.0

Answer (score -3):

Multi-index columns cannot be exported to Excel. It is possible to transform the multi-index to single index, and then export it to excelc.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.to_excel('file_name.xlsx', index=False)
```